# Catalyst/Moose: make log object always available to outside module

Tags: perl, moose, catalyst

I have a large Catalyst application, which has its own logging system (apart from the built-in Catalyst log); a set-up routine makes the log object available in the stash as `$c->stash->{log}`. (Different controllers have different log objects, with outputs going to different places.)

This app has a large Utilities package, with many dozens of generally small functions that take care of a variety of tasks (along the lines of `get_name_from_id` or `cleanse_input` or `convert_date`). This package is dedicated to this Catalyst app alone, i.e. it's not shared by any outside application.

Is there a way I can make the log object available to the entire Utilities package, without having to pass it manually every time? I assume there's some neat Moose way of doing this, but my Moose-fu is poor....

Answer (score 2):

Don't put it on the stash. Split the utilities library. Employ [roles](http://p3rl.org/Moose::Manual::Roles) where you need shared functionality.

```
package Loggable {
    use Moose::Role;
    sub log {
        ... # implementation goes here
    }
}

package SomeController {
    use Moose;
    with 'Loggable';

    ...
}

my $c = SomeController->new;
$c->can('log') # true
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you clarify how that would be used by the Utilities library? (I guess the same thing would apply to making the logging class available to a regular Model class within Catalyst, perhaps a more common need.)

Comment: @user1235777 it sounds like some of these shouldn't be in a utility package, but rather composed into the Catalyst application itself, or done via roles like daxim suggested for the log method. You _could_ pass around the thing that is calling the utility function (like `clean_input($self, $data)` or `$self->Utilities::clean_input($data)`, actually). But I don't like that much. It's confusing. Why does each controller have a different log config?

Comment: @simbabque First of all, I wasn't clear how I would use the roles in the utility package; that's what I was asking for an explanation of. Second, each controller is responsible for a different part of the app, so each one needs to log to a different file.

Comment: @user You don't use the role in the utility at all. You use it in the Controller. That composes that behaviour into that Controller class. It can then log. The logging should really be done by the Controller, not the Utility thingy. Are you using something like Log4perl?

Comment: Log::Dispatch. In any case, the Controller is indeed doing the logging, and while I agree that roles are probably a better way of doing it than putting it in the stash, that's not the real issue here.... For the most part we don't need to log from Utility, but sometimes we'd like to, esp. for debugging purposes, and it would be nice to just have access to the existing log object instead of manually adding it into the Utility code.